# oradim intpwd problem creating database password with a space

Tags: oracle

I'm using oradim to create an instance. Althoug it works, when I use a space in the password, the command gives me next warning or error:

```
 There must be no spaces around the equal-to (=) character.
Instance created.
```

The command I'm using is:

```
oradim -new -sid dbname -intpwd "S sypass123!" -startmode auto -srvcstart system -pfile C:\Oracle\19c_server\database\database\initdbname.ora
```

The sys user does seem to be created with that password, but do I need to worry about that error/warning message?

Comment: That's more for DBAs (I'm not the one), but "There must be no spaces around the equal-to (=) character." error is either *misreporting*, or something else has happened because there's **no** `=` sign anywhere in that command. Maybe I don't understand it, but error doesn't say anything about space you put into password. My suggestion: wait for DBA to see your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably has to do with how DOS handles parameters. Following works:

```
oradim -new -sid dbname -intpwd "\"S sypass123!\"" -startmode auto -srvcstart system -pfile C:\Oracle\19c_server\database\database\initdbname.ora
```

Answer (score 1):

The message is coming from the `orapwd` command, which is used under the hood during database creation to create the external password file for SYS authentication. I'm not sure it has anything to do with your actual password, as that isn't included in that command. I'd have to see the specific command being generated, as well as the associated `create database` SQL command where the SYS password is actually set.

That said, using special characters in Oracle passwords is always a bit of a crap shoot. Success (or failure) depends very much on the specific tools being used, how they present the connection request to Oracle, and whether or not use of a command-line shell is involved (as when using sqlplus or sqlcl). Different operating systems react differently to specific characters that may be reserved or have special meaning (like "!", "$", "%", or "&"). I've worked with dozens of different OS variations over the years, and the only special character that seems to work universally across all of them, regardless of the tool or UI, is the underscore: "_".

Comment: Thx for the help. The "S sypass123!" was probably given to orapwd as S sypass123! ... See my own answer.